# How to compare the Integer included the string in a loop

Tags: java

I want to compare the number of the file name "AB123456","DF321654" and "KR852963". That code just can display the number of smaller and largest but cannot display the full name such as "AB","DF" and "KR". Please advice me!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        File folder = new File("input/");
        File [] files = folder.listFiles();      

        //Set first number as smallest and largest   
        long smallest = getNumberFromName(files[0]);
        long largest = smallest;

        //Get number for each file and assign smallest & largest values
        for(int i = 1; i < files.length-1;i++) {
            long nextNumber = getNumberFromName(files[i]);
            if (smallest > nextNumber)
                smallest = nextNumber
            if (largest < nextNumber)
                largest = nextNumber
        }
        System.out.println("The smallest number="+smallest)
        System.out.println("The biggest number="+largest)
    }    

    private static long getNumberFromName(File nextFile) {
        String fileFullName = nextFile.getName();       
        String fileSimple= fileFullName.substring(2,fileFullName.length()-4);           
        return Long.parseLong(fileSimple);
    }
```

Comment: Because you have use `substring()` to truncate them

Comment: @ lucumt, please advice me for code

Comment: You can make those file name into an array of string and try to parse them to long if there is an error meaning they are string.           Use try catch method, if the string is parsable to long then add that string to a string variable to be parsed to long at the end.

Comment: @Leroy,  please advice me for code

Answer (score 1):

You can use two additional strings to store the original string vlaue,then output it,also your code can not compile due to you have lack of `;` for the `if` check

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        File folder = new File("input/");
        File [] files = folder.listFiles();      

        //Set first number as smallest and largest   
        long smallest = getNumberFromName(files[0]);
        long largest = smallest;
        String smallestStr,largestStr = null;

        //Get number for each file and assign smallest & largest values
        for(int i = 1; i < files.length-1;i++) {
            long nextNumber = getNumberFromName(files[i]);
            if (smallest > nextNumber){
                smallest = nextNumber;//you have missing ; here
                smallestStr = files[i].getName();
            }
            if (largest < nextNumber){
                largest = nextNumber;//you have missing ; here
                largestStr = files[i].getName();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The smallest number="+smallestStr)
        System.out.println("The biggest number="+largestStr)
    }    

    private static long getNumberFromName(File nextFile) {
        String fileFullName = nextFile.getName();       
        String fileSimple= fileFullName.substring(2,fileFullName.length()-4);           
        return Long.parseLong(fileSimple);
    }
```

Comment: I got the error of smallestStr = files[i];  and largestStr = files[i];
which pointed that "cannot convert from file to string";

Comment: @buybuy you need to invoke `getName()` before assign it to a string variable

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain extra state for the full filenames.  The only major change to your code below is that when encountering a new minimum or maximum number, we also record the full filename, in addition to the numeric prefix.

```
File folder = new File("input/");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();      

long smallest = getNumberFromName(files[0]);
long largest = smallest;
String sFile = files[0].getName();
String lFile = sFile;

for (int i=1; i < files.length; i++) {
    long nextNumber = getNumberFromName(files[i]);
    if (smallest > nextNumber) {
        smallest = nextNumber;
        sFile = files[i].getName();
    }
    else if (largest < nextNumber) {
        largest = nextNumber;
        lFile = files[i].getName();
    }
}

System.out.println("The smallest number = " + smallest + ", file = " + sFile);
System.out.println("The largest number = " + largest + ", file = " + lFile);
```

Note that your current approach is already fairly lean in that it does not bother with storing the entire collection as you iterate.  Rather, you only keep track of the minimum and maximum entries.

Comment: "The smallest number = " display the correct file name of smallest. "The largest number = " display the incorrect file name of largest which display the middle number of file name.

Comment: @buybuy I don't see any problem with my logic, so my guess is that your data has a problem.

Comment: my code has the problem which not your logic problem!

Comment: @buy I am not "buying" your observations, and my answer should be working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
private static long getNumberFromName(File nextFile) {
    String fileFullName = nextFile.getName();
    String retStrLong = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < fileFullName.length()-1; i++){

       try{
          Long.parseLong(fileFullName[i]);
          retStrLong = retStrLong+fileFullName[i];
       }catch(){
          continue;
       }
    }
    return Long.parseLong(retStrLong);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can match the file name with a regex, if it matches then fetch the number else you can decide what to do, for now I am returning the least long value possible if the file name doesn't match the regex. Please refer the below code.

```
private static long getNumberFromName(File nextFile)
{
    /*This is th regex for the file name,
    starts with any combination of string values and will have to end with some number*/
    String fileNameRegex = "^([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]+)$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(fileNameRegex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nextFile.getName());
    // If the pattern matches we will return the long value present in the name else the min of the long.
    return matcher.find() ? Long.valueOf(matcher.group(2)) : Long.MIN_VALUE;
}
```